# is it possible to add static users in cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, serverless

I am using serverless framework and want to add some static users

I created successfully the group and the users pool

```
 Resources:
    AdminUserPoolGroup:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolGroup
    Properties:
       GroupName: admin
       Precedence: 0
       UserPoolId: 
         Ref: CognitoUserPool
```

I want to know if it is possible to add some static users statically in serverless.yml (for example a root user for my app) in yml.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`AWS::Cognito::UserPoolUser`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-userpooluser.html) to provision users in your User Pool:

```yam
Resources:
  ...
  AdminUser:
    Type: 'AWS::Cognito::UserPoolUser'
    Properties:
      ...
      UserPoolId: !Ref CognitoUserPool
      ...
```